# creatable select issue in iis hosting

Tags: reactjs, iis, react-select

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import BootstrapSwitchButton from 'bootstrap-switch-button-react'
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
function StaffReg() {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');

    const apiBaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL;




    //////select////
    const handleSelect = (value, fieldName) => {
        // Check if value is not null or undefined before accessing its 'value' property
        if (value && value.value) {
            // Update the formData state with the selected value
            setFormData({ ...formData, [fieldName]: value.value });
        }
    };

    const idInputRef = useRef(null);
    const nameInputRef = useRef(null);
    const sectionInputRef = useRef(null);
    const genderInputRef = useRef(null);
    const address1InputRef = useRef(null);
    const address2InputRef = useRef(null);
    const address3InputRef = useRef(null);
    const mobileInputRef = useRef(null);
    const typeInputRef = useRef(null);
    const dateOjInputRef = useRef(null);
    const salaryInputRef = useRef(null);
    const otRateInputRef = useRef(null);
    const otHourInputRef = useRef(null);
    const leaveDeductionInputRef = useRef(null);
    const dailyAllowanceInputRef = useRef(null);
    const activecheckBoxInputRef = useRef(null);
    const casualLeaveInputRef = useRef(null);
    const branchInputRef = useRef(null);
    const commissionStatusInputRef = useRef(null);
    const percentInputRef = useRef(null);
    const pfInputRef = useRef(null);
    const workingHoursInputRef = useRef(null);
    const ledgerInputRef = useRef(null);
    const userNameInputRef = useRef(null);
    const passwordInputRef = useRef(null);
    const tabsRef = useRef(null);

    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('Payroll');
    console.log('selected tab =', selectedTab);



    useEffect(() => {
        idInputRef.current.focus();
    }, []);

    const handleKeyDown = (event, nextInputRef, nextTabKey) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            nextInputRef.current.focus();
            console.log('Switching to tab:', nextTabKey);


            setSelectedTab(nextTabKey);


        }
    };

    return (

        <Layout style={{ minHeight: '150vh' }}>
            {/* Use the Sidebar component here */}
            <Sidebar collapsed={collapsed} onCollapse={(value) => setCollapsed(value)} />

            <Layout>

                <div className='staffreg-root-div'>
<div className='staff-registration-form'>
                        <div className='staffreg-emp-id-div form-margin'>


                            <FormLabel className='staffreg-formlabel-employeeId'> Employees Id</FormLabel>
                            <input
                                ref={idInputRef}
                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, nameInputRef)}

                                value={employeeId}
                                className='staffreg-input-employeeId' />


                        </div>
                        <div className='staff-reg-employeeName form-margin'>
                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeName'> Employees Name</FormLabel>


                            <CreatableSelect
                              
                                ref={nameInputRef}
                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, sectionInputRef)}
                                styles={{
                                    control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                                        ...baseStyles,
                                        borderColor: 'black',
                                        height: '35px',
                                        minHeight: '10px',
                                        marginTop: '0',

                                    }),
                                    placeholder: (baseStyles) => ({
                                        ...baseStyles,
                                        display: 'none',  // Hide the placeholder
                                    }),
                                }}

                                isClearable
                                options={employeeNames.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }))}
                                formatCreateLabel={() => null}
                                className='staffreg-employeeNameComboBox'
                                onChange={(selectedOption) => handleSelect(selectedOption, 'sr_Name')}


                            />

                            <Button className='employee-Rename-Button'> Rename</Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='staff-reg-emplyee-section form-margin'>
                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeSection'> Section</FormLabel>

                            <CreatableSelect
                                ref={sectionInputRef}
                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, genderInputRef)}
                                styles={{
                                    control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                                        ...baseStyles,
                                        borderColor: 'black',
                                        height: '35px',
                                        minHeight: '10px',
                                        marginTop: '0',
                                    }),
                                    placeholder: (baseStyles) => ({
                                        ...baseStyles,
                                        display: 'none',  // Hide the placeholder
                                    }),
                                }}

                                isClearable
                                options={options2.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }))}
                                formatCreateLabel={() => null}
                                className='staffreg-employeeSectionComboBox'
                                onChange={(selectedOption) => handleSelect(selectedOption, 'sr_Section')}
                            />

                        </div>
                       


                       

                        <div className='staff-reg-emplyee-Mobile form-margin'>
                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeMobile'> Mobile</FormLabel>
                            <input
                                ref={mobileInputRef}
                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, typeInputRef)}
                                value={formData.sr_Mobile}
                                onChange={(e) =>
                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_Mobile: e.target.value })
                                } className='input-employeeMobile' />
                        </div>


                        <div className='staff-reg-emplyee-Tabs form-margin'>
                            <Tabs
                                ref={tabsRef}
                                defaultActiveKey={selectedTab}
                                onSelect={(tabKey) => setSelectedTab(tabKey)}
                                transition={false}
                                id="noanim-tab-example"
                                className="mb-3 staff-reg-tab"
                            >
                                <Tab eventKey="Payroll" title="Payroll">
                                    <div className='staffreg-tab-line1 form-margin'>
                                        <div className='employeeType-div'>

                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeType'> Type</FormLabel>


                                            <CreatableSelect
                                                ref={typeInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, dateOjInputRef)}
                                                styles={{
                                                    control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                                                        ...baseStyles,
                                                        borderColor: 'black',
                                                        height: '35px',
                                                        minHeight: '10px',
                                                        marginTop: '0',
                                                        borderRadius: '0',
                                                    }),
                                                    placeholder: (baseStyles) => ({
                                                        ...baseStyles,
                                                        display: 'none',  // Hide the placeholder
                                                    }),
                                                }}

                                                isClearable
                                                options={options3.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }))}
                                                formatCreateLabel={() => null}
                                                className='staffreg-employeeTypeComboBox'
                                                onChange={(selectedOption) => handleSelect(selectedOption, 'sr_Type')}
                                            />

                                        </div>
                                        <div className='employeeDateofjoin-div'>

                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeDateofjoin'> Date Of Join</FormLabel>
                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeDateofjoin-mobile'> DOJ</FormLabel>
                                            <input
                                                ref={dateOjInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, salaryInputRef)}

                                                value={formData.sr_DateOj} onChange={(e) =>
                                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_DateOj: e.target.value })
                                                } type='date' className='input-employeeDateofjoin' />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='staffreg-tab-line2 form-margin'>
                                        <div className='employeeBasicSalary-div'>

                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeBasicSalary'> Basic Salary</FormLabel>
                                            <input
                                                ref={salaryInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, otRateInputRef)}

                                                value={formData.sr_Salary} onChange={(e) =>
                                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_Salary: e.target.value })
                                                } className=' input-employeeBasicSalary' />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='employeeOtRate-div'>

                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeOtRate'> O.T Rate</FormLabel>
                                            <input
                                                ref={otRateInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, otHourInputRef)}
                                                value={formData.sr_OtRate} onChange={(e) =>
                                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_OtRate: e.target.value })
                                                } className='input-employeeOtRate' />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='staffreg-tab-line3 form-margin'>
                                        <div className='employeeOtHour-div'>

                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeOtHour'> O.T Hour</FormLabel>
                                            <input
                                                ref={otHourInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, leaveDeductionInputRef)}
                                                value={formData.sr_OtHour} onChange={(e) =>
                                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_OtHour: e.target.value })
                                                } className=' input-employeeOtHour' />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='employeeLeaveDeduction-div'>

                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeLeaveDeduction'> Leave Deduction</FormLabel>
                                            <input
                                                ref={leaveDeductionInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, dailyAllowanceInputRef)}
                                                value={formData.sr_LeaveDeduction} onChange={(e) =>
                                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_LeaveDeduction: e.target.value })
                                                } className='input-employeeLeaveDeduction' />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className='staffreg-tab-line4 form-margin'>
                                        <div className='employeeDailyAllowances-div'>
                                            {/* style={{whiteSpace:'nowrap'}} */}
                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeDailyAllowances' > Daily Allowances</FormLabel>
                                            <input
                                                ref={dailyAllowanceInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, activecheckBoxInputRef)}
                                                value={formData.sr_DailyAllowance} onChange={(e) =>
                                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_DailyAllowance: e.target.value })
                                                } className=' input-employeeDailyAllowances' />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='employeeLeaveDeduction-div'>
                                            <Form.Check
                                                ref={activecheckBoxInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, casualLeaveInputRef)}
                                                onChange={(e) =>
                                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_Active: e.target.checked ? 1 : 0 })
                                                }
                                                className="employee-reg-checkBox custom-checkbox"
                                                label="Active"
                                                aria-label="option 1"
                                            />
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div className='staffreg-tab-line5 form-margin'>
                                        <div className='employeeCasualLeave-div'>

                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeCasualLeave'> Casual Leave/Yr</FormLabel>
                                            <input
                                                ref={casualLeaveInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, branchInputRef)}
                                                value={formData.sr_CasualLeave} onChange={(e) =>
                                                    setFormData({ ...formData, sr_CasualLeave: e.target.value })
                                                } className=' input-employeeCasualLeave' />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='employeeBranch-div'>

                                            <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeBranch'> Branch</FormLabel>


                                            <CreatableSelect
                                                ref={branchInputRef}
                                                onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, commissionStatusInputRef, 'Details')}

                                                styles={{
                                                    control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                                                        ...baseStyles,
                                                        borderColor: 'black',
                                                        height: '35px',
                                                        minHeight: '10px',
                                                        marginTop: '0',
                                                        borderRadius: '0',
                                                    }),
                                                    placeholder: (baseStyles) => ({
                                                        ...baseStyles,
                                                        display: 'none',  // Hide the placeholder
                                                    }),
                                                }}

                                                isClearable
                                                options={options4.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }))}
                                                formatCreateLabel={() => null}
                                                className='staffreg-employeeBranchComboBox'
                                                onChange={(selectedOption) => handleSelect(selectedOption, 'sr_Branch')}

                                            />


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Tab>
                                <Tab eventKey="Details" title="Details">
                                    <div className='staffreg-tab-line1 form-margin'>


                                        <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeCommissionStatus'> Commission Status</FormLabel>


                                        <CreatableSelect
                                            ref={commissionStatusInputRef}
                                            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, percentInputRef)}
                                            styles={{
                                                control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                                                    ...baseStyles,
                                                    borderColor: 'black',
                                                    height: '35px',
                                                    minHeight: '10px',
                                                    marginTop: '0',
                                                    borderRadius: '0',
                                                }),
                                                placeholder: (baseStyles) => ({
                                                    ...baseStyles,
                                                    display: 'none',  // Hide the placeholder
                                                }),
                                            }}

                                            isClearable
                                            options={options3.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }))}
                                            formatCreateLabel={() => null}
                                            className='staffreg-employeeCommissionStatusComboBox'
                                            onChange={(selectedOption) => handleSelect(selectedOption, 'sr_CommissionStatus')}
                                        />


                                        <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeCommissionStatusperc'> %</FormLabel>
                                        <input
                                            ref={percentInputRef}
                                            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, pfInputRef)}
                                            value={formData.sr_Percent} onChange={(e) =>
                                                setFormData({ ...formData, sr_Percent: e.target.value })
                                            } className='input-employeeCommissionStatusperc' />

                                    </div>
                                    <div className='employeePF-div form-margin'>

                                        <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeePF'> P.F</FormLabel>
                                        <input
                                            ref={pfInputRef}
                                            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, workingHoursInputRef)}
                                            value={formData.sr_Pf} onChange={(e) =>
                                                setFormData({ ...formData, sr_Pf: e.target.value })
                                            } className=' input-employeePF' />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='employeeWorkingHours-div form-margin'>

                                        <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeWorkingHours'> Working Hours</FormLabel>
                                        <input
                                            ref={workingHoursInputRef}
                                            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, ledgerInputRef)}
                                            value={formData.sr_WorkingHours} onChange={(e) =>
                                                setFormData({ ...formData, sr_WorkingHours: e.target.value })
                                            } className=' input-employeeWorkingHours' />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='employeeLedger-div form-margin'>

                                        <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeLedger'> Ledger</FormLabel>


                                        <CreatableSelect
                                            ref={ledgerInputRef}
                                            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, userNameInputRef, 'Payrollapp')}
                                            styles={{
                                                control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
                                                    ...baseStyles,
                                                    borderColor: 'black',
                                                    height: '35px',
                                                    minHeight: '10px',
                                                    marginTop: '0',
                                                    borderRadius: '0',
                                                }),
                                                placeholder: (baseStyles) => ({
                                                    ...baseStyles,
                                                    display: 'none',  // Hide the placeholder
                                                }),
                                            }}

                                            isClearable
                                            options={options6.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }))}
                                            formatCreateLabel={() => null}
                                            className='staffreg-employeeLedgerComboBox'
                                            onChange={(selectedOption) => handleSelect(selectedOption, 'sr_Ledger')}
                                        />

                                    </div>

                                </Tab>
                                <Tab eventKey="Payrollapp" title="Payroll App" >
                                    <div className='employeeUserName-div form-margin'>
                                        <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeeUserName'> UserName</FormLabel>
                                        <input
                                            ref={userNameInputRef}
                                            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, passwordInputRef)}
                                            value={formData.sr_UserName} onChange={(e) =>
                                                setFormData({ ...formData, sr_UserName: e.target.value })
                                            } className=' input-employeeUserName' />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='employeePassword-div form-margin'>
                                        <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeePassword'> Password</FormLabel>
                                        <input
                                            ref={passwordInputRef}
                                            //  onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e, dateOjInputRef)}
                                            value={formData.sr_Password} onChange={(e) =>
                                                setFormData({ ...formData, sr_Password: e.target.value })
                                            } className=' input-employeePassword' />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='employeePassword-div form-margin'>
                                        <FormLabel className='formlabel-employeePassword'>App Enable</FormLabel>
                                        <BootstrapSwitchButton
                                            onChange={(checked) => setFormData({ ...formData, sr_AppEnable: checked ? 1 : 0 })}
                                            checked={true}  // You may want to use formData.sr_AppEnable instead of always setting it to true
                                            onstyle="primary"
                                            offstyle="light"
                                            size='sm'
                                        />
                                    </div>


                                </Tab>
                            </Tabs>


                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </Layout>
        </Layout>


    )
}

export default StaffReg
```

when i host this project see its output on mobile view .i am not able to type value in the ceatable select input boxes.after enter a value in that creatable input box when the focus moves to the next input box the already entered input values are clears.but when i uses a physical keyboard to enter in the mobile .there in no issue it is working properly.i have only the probem in the android devices

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.